# Tortoisesvn on web server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, shared-hosting

Is there a way to add a repository on my linux shared webhosting to use with tortoisesvn? Or is there something similar I can do as easy as using tortoise without buying hosting strictly for a repository like cvsdude or something?

Comment: Does that Linux host come with SVN's server components installed?

Comment: I don't see it anywhere so I don't think so, it is a Lunarpages basic hosting plan

Comment: Thanks guys, I am checking out the free hosting from xp-dev.com. So now that my repo is set up and I have the address, is it possible to add this to tortoise svn or do I have to do something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot install new software on your shared host you either need to run a server you can control (like an old machine with Linux hooked up to your router with NAT port forwarding and a DynDNS alias so you can access your repository while on the road) or you'll have to use a commercial provider.  [These guys](http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing) have a free plan which looks like it could get you started.  (Never tried that provider, its just one of the first ones that comes up when I search.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the instructions on how to setup [Apache to serve up an SVN repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).

Personally, I have a linux box at home that runs [`svnserve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) on a port I opened on my router. It works great for small projects.